# How to get dynamic html elements, while it is only visible when we scroll down to ***px

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get all elements of site using xpath but it return only few elements instead of all elements,

Xpath---- "//[@id="js-CTGY"]/main/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul//li"

Site---- https://www.sewingpartsonline.com/alphasew-221-sewing-machine-parts.aspx?filter.ptype_gmcfeed_1=%20Machine%20Needles&sort.ss_cat_sort=desc&index=164

is there any way to get all elements using C# Htmlagility

Code:

```
string path="https://www.sewingpartsonline.com/alphasew-221-sewing-machine-parts.aspx?sort.ss_cat_sort=desc&index=164";

 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(path);
 var HeaderNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id="js-CTGY"]/main/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul//li").ToList();
```

Comment: You should include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.